# Add delay to scrollTop?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add a delay to scrollTop function, strictly in the code below?

```
function btns(evt, btnName) {
  var i, containerMain, tablinks; 
  containerMain = document.getElementsByClassName("containerMain");
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementById(btnName).classList.add('active');
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].scrollLeft = 0;
    containerMain[i].scrollTop = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, it is, you can use `setTimeout`

Comment: @CalvinNunes Can you provide a full code?

Comment: right now, I can, because I'm with free time, but in StackOverflow we expect a little effort from askers, showing that at least you tried something instead of just ask for free full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use `setInterval` and clear the timer when all the elements are scrolled.

```
function btns(evt, btnName) {
  var i, containerMain, tablinks; 
  containerMain = document.getElementsByClassName("containerMain");
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementById(btnName).classList.add('active');
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].scrollLeft = 0;
  }
  i=0;
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    containerMain[i++].scrollTop = 0;
    if(i >= containerMain.length) clearInterval(timer);
  }, 1000);
}
```